# Subtract a series with itself with a time difference of say 24 hours in Influxdb

Tags: influxdb

I have a measurement with some fields. I have to get a difference of a data point lets say at 12 noon today with 12 noon yesterday. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can add/subtract 2 queries output.
I am using it in this way -
For e.g -

```
select sum(status) as Status from series where group_id='2177' and time> '2017-03-10 00:00:00' and time<'2017-05-10 00:00:00';select sum(status) as Status2 from series where group_id='2177' and time> '2017-04-10 00:00:00';
```

name: series
time            Status
----            ------
1489104000000000001 1058

name: series
time            Status2
----            -------
1491782400000000001 591

Atlast, you can subtract them to get the output (Status - Status2).

Let me know, if it can be used to solve your problem.

Comment: I feel the result of the query will be a single number and not a series, i would like to get two series and then subtract those. I will try your solution though thanks for the reply, will let you know if it works.

Comment: unfortunately , for now this is only solution available with influxdb probably you need to write such logic at your own. please upvote it if you find it useful . thanks

Comment: I will also add update if I find anything useful related to this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, currently proceeding with writing a python script that pulls data from influx and does the calculation, I hope that is the right path.